# Людмила,нужно помогать людям! Я не могу подобрать 2 аргумента по этому тексту

Tags: обучение

помогите пожалуйста написать сочинение
    (1)Отбряцал доспехами День защитника Отечества, отбабахало пробочными салютами шампанско-цветочное 8 марта. (2)Отговорили мы тосты, отдарили подарки, отсмеялись, отрадовались. (З)Всё.

(4)Праздники кончились. (5)Теперь до мая будет тянуться слякотное и серое окончание зимы. (6)По её кончине робкой девушкой войдёт в промозглую, талую нашу горницу весна; холодным ещё, стылым покрывалом накроет чёрные голые ветви деревьев, пепельную прошлогоднюю траву, сор и грязь раскисших парков и скверов. (7)Грустно и уныло будет кругом.

(8)Не очень весёлые недели предстоят нам. (9)Тем более, по прогнозам синоптиков, весна в этом году будет поздняя и не тёплая. (Ю)Можно смириться и принять — так, дескать, было всегда: делу время, потехе — час, на то они и праздники, чтобы быстро заканчиваться.

(11)А смирившись и приняв невесёлую эту реальность, опять нырнуть в повседневность, отложить радость и ощущение полноты жизни до следующих официальных праздников. (12)На этот раз — майских.

(13) Многие так живут. (14)Да почти все. (15)Особенно сейчас, когда не то что жить, просто выживать становится всё труднее. (16)А многие и этих, официальных, уже не замечают — не до них, не до веселья.

(17)«Хлеб наш насущный даждь нам днесь...»

(18)Впрочем, всё это о празднествах календарных, заявленных.

(19)И, повторюсь, с внутренними, в душе располагающимися, они не всегда совпадают. (20)Хемингуэй писал о Париже: «Праздник, который всегда с тобой». (21)Носимый в сердце, дарящий радость, счастье, довольство. (22)Но разве обязателен для таких ощущений Париж?

(23)Был у меня приятель. (24)Он свой праздник носил в душе постоянно. (25)Всегда приветлив, улыбчив, доброжелателен, радостен.

(26)Даже, бывало, когда белый свет не мил. (27)Даже после сумасшедшего редакционного дня, когда еле ноги домой волочишь. (28)Светлый был парень, искрящийся весь, словно мёд на просвет против солнца. (29)Занимала меня в нём эта черта, необъяснимой казалась. (ЗО)Однажды не выдержал, спросил.

(31)— А у меня, — говорит, — напротив балкона три сосны растут. (32)Утром их жёлтые стволы заря розовым светом пропитывает, насыщает так, что они прозрачными кажутся. (ЗЗ)Ну будто спелый ананас — вот-вот сок брызнет. (34)И тёмная зелень кроны, и небо, уже не окрашенное зарёй, а чистое, голубое, высокое... (Зб)Красоти-ща — дух захватывает, плакать хочется, как красиво. (Зб)Вот я с утра пару минут полюбуюсь и на целый день заряд оптимизма получаю...

(37)— А если пасмурно или в темноте встать придётся? — спрашиваю.

(38)—Глаза закрою и увижу. (39)Главное — захотеть. (40)Когда в командировке окажусь или на отдыхе, обязательно ищу, на что с утра полюбоваться. (41)Красота повсюду вокруг нас разлита. (42)Захочешь — увидишь. (43)Захотеть главное.

(44)С тех пор мне часто доводилось прибегать к этому совету. (45)И каждый раз получалось. (46)Начинался праздник и в душе, и в сердце. (47)И жизнь светлей и радостней казалась, несмотря на слякоть и серость в природе. (48)Попробуйте и вы, читатель, вдруг и вам совет этот поможет дожить с хорошим настроением до следующих официальных праздников. (49)Всего-то и нужно, не забыть посмотреть вокруг.
(По М. Беляту)

Comment: Меня одного этот заголовок заставляет вспомнить Груианта?

Comment: Имейте совесть, Людмила и так вам помогла! См. сочинение

Comment: behemothus, с Вашими опечатками - и смех и грех. Читаю и думаю, кто такой Груиат? Почему я не помню такого литературного героя?))) Срочно набираю в поисковике - яндекс исправляет на груманта))).

Comment: >behemothus, с Вашими опечатками - и смех и грех.   
  
Ну вот, главное - гугл меня понимает.   
А вообще-то, конечно, беда...

Comment: Народ, прекратите  переходить на личности!! Это относится и в автору вопроса в том числе.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь две проблемы:1. Проблема отношения к официальным праздникам.
2. Что такое внутренние праздники и какова их роль?

Авторская позиция:
1. Непростая жизнь россиян ведёт к тому, что многие люди просто не замечают официальных праздников, погрузившись в прозу жизни.
2. Следует культивировать в себе внутренние праздники, то есть праздники в душе и в сердце. Как? Уметь видеть красоту вокруг, любоваться красотами природы, например. Тогда и официальные праздники будут восприниматься по-другому, с хорошим настроением.

Аргументы:
    1.В.Вересаев в книге "Мать.Из записной книжки"  рассказывает  о том, как он увидел в Дрездене «Сикстинскую мадонну» Рафаэля. Картина наполнила радостью его душу, он был горд за человечество, которое сумело воплотить и вознести на высоту такое материнство: мадонна предчувствовала подвиг сына. Она не прижимала его к себе, не пыталась защитить от  будущего, она гордилась им. И автору хотелось молиться ей, хотя он был неверующим.

2.Б.Екимов «Музыка старого дома». Этюды Шишкина, Серова в Русском музее помогли рассказчику увидеть красоту земли, людей, жизни.

3.Ю. Яковлев  «Разбуженный соловьями». Озорного, непоседливого Селюжонка однажды в пионерском лагере разбудили соловьи. Рассердившись, с камнем в руке, он решает расправиться с птицами, но замирает, завороженный пением соловья. Что- то стронулось в душе мальчика, ему захотелось увидеть, а потом и изобразить лесного волшебника.  Когда соловей снова разбудил его, он поднял с кроватей всех ребят, чтобы те тоже услышали волшебные трели. Автор утверждает, что постижение красоты в природе ведет к постижению красоты в искусстве, в себе, дарит радость праздника.

4.У героя Шукшина в рассказе "Чудик" в душе был праздник, он видел красоту вокруг, умел ей радоваться, дарил эту красоту и свою любовь людям, правда, его не понимали, потому что жили скучно, серо.

Comment: Это аргументы к соч. по второй проблеме